# location based With Markerless augmented reality android application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, location-based

i want to build an augmented reality app which should be Markerless (without any previous target) and location based.Basically i want it like when i run my app and keep the camera on ground it shows me a cube and next day when i will open that app then the cube will show me on that same position.I search a lot in which i observe that vuforia is not work on markerless, wikitude location based is not work on unity and kudan is work on 64 bit OS so that i cant work on them Please suggest me more which SdK i can use for my project I already see the previous stack tutorials but i am so confused please help me out of this problem.

Comment: Vuforia now supports device tracking world center mode which apply mobile device rotation to AR camera object in the scene.